# Does google-assistant-sdk support for other languages?

Tags: android, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I knew google assistant SDK has been released, but the default language is English, does it support for other languages?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the release notes from Google found here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes

From April 27th, English is the only supported language for alpha v1 release (language tag "EN-US").

For the 0.0.2 May 17th release, there is no statement about supported languages.

But when you create Actions on Google using API.ai you can choose which language the Action will be.

[image: api.ai create new agent window]